# Jmeter gives data usage value in exponential format in response data. How to convert exponential value to numberr format?

Tags: python-3.x, api, jmeter

I am trying to read the values from csv file for comparison in jmeter using json asertion. When it is more than 10 letters in a cell in csv it is displaying in exponential form like "value":3.908327965E9 when test case run. but real number what i given in csv is "value":3908327965.0 , How can i convert the above exponential form to original number in jmeter.

Comment: Double click on the column to extend or click on the cell and check the value in the formula bar. It should display the expected value without exponential. It is visible mostly when the cell or column is compressed but display properly if expanded.

Comment: I want solution for jmeter , csv showing correct but jmeter in response data gives exponential value

Comment: Please show your plan..request and response with that variable to get quick response. If your request is sending the correct data then it is server which is sending the response in exponential format.